# WP: popup dialogue box for authentication

Tags: wordpress

I'm experiencing a problem when I go my site there's a dialogue box that will show up for authentication. I don't know what it was for.

here's the image. [image]

Comment: check the .htpasswd file is present in wordpress root folder and remove the auth lines in .htaccess

Comment: okay sir. where can I find the .htpasswd file and .htaccess? i'm still new to wp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in to your CGI server using a command line FTP program, or an FTP program that lets you see hidden files in directories. Some FTP programs may have a setting for this. Find and delete your .htaccess file you are changing on your CGI server (see below).

Deleting An .htaccess File

If you go into a directory on your CGI server where you're sure you have an .htaccess file, but can not find it to delete it, this is because the file is hidden. Any file that starts with a dot (.) is not normally shown in most FTP programs. You will have to set up your FTP program to view all files, include hidden ones and then select the .htaccess file and delete it once you can see it.

If you are using a command line FTP program, here are some suggested steps you can take. Most command line FTP programs use the same basic commands. The text in bold is what you would type in. yourdomain.com is to be replaced with your actual domain name.

```
ftp> open cgi.yourdomain.com
Name: yourdomain.com
Password: your_password
ftp> delete .htaccess
ftp> bye
```

Comment: how can I unhide the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

I found an article by *Alex Rowley* on WebHostingPad forum. It appears that WebHostingPad has added additional anti-robot authentication and Google Chrome did an update that broke the Authentication popup.
The work around is to open the page in another browser, I tried IE, and the popup will have the information needed to get past the authentication. I used the information on my Chrome popup so I can continue to use Chrome.